# Regex check length in range

Tags: regex

These are the requirements:

- 1 Uppercase
- 1 Lowercase
- 1 Special character
- 1 Number (0-9)
- Total length is 12-16

I currently have this expression, which works as expected:

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W)
```

This checks for everything except length, so this is valid `Aa2@`

How do I add the length check of 12-16 characters?

Comment: Try: `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W)\S{12,16}$`

Comment: That works! if you make an answer i'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Dupe doesn't seem correct as it is not just about missing length check, this regex would need anchors as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is:

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W)
```

Those are set of lookahead assertions to enforce certain rules of your requirements. However that regex is not consuming any characters in the match and that's where you can use `.{12,16}` or `\S{12,16}` range quantifier to restrict input to `12` to `16` characters. So following solutions should work for you:

```sh
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W)\S{12,16}$
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W).{12,16}$
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W)(?=.{12,16}$)
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W)(?=\S{12,16}$)
```

A `.` will match any character but `\S` matches a non-whitespace character only.